# oracle query not getting count as 0 with group by and count query , instead getting empty row

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper, aggregate-functions

This is the query and we dont have data for location# =83 but i want output as cnt=0

```
SELECT
            COUNT(1) AS cnt , location# as  record_no
        FROM
            test
        WHERE
                cny# = 1
            AND location# = 83 group by location#
```

getting the output as empty row, instead expected out similar to this like

```
     cny
---|-----
 1    0
```

With below query i m getting the expected output

```
SELECT
            COUNT(1) AS cnt 
        FROM
            test
        WHERE
                cny# = 1
            AND location# =83
```

How can i get same output as shown in expected above with using group by and adding the column in select as in top query i have shown

Comment: 2 queries, 2 different tables. Why is 1st query (that selects from TEST) supposed to know that LOCATION# = 83 exists? What about locations 5382 or 328? I mean: where do locations come from? Did you consider **outer joining** TEST to table that contains locations?

Comment: @Littlefoot both are same table , le me correct it, its updated now

Comment: @Littlefoot so What about locations 5382 or 328? , so consider some locations are found and then the output is correct i mean it is working as expected but if no data found then it is giving empty instead i want 0 with that column cnt is that possible ?

Comment: the difference is because when you add the group by, and you have no rows to group, you get no result. In the second case you count how many rows the query returns, and it tells you zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

 LOCATION#       CNY#
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          1
        83         22
```

This, as you know, works:

```
SQL> select count(*)
  2  from test
  3  where cny# = 1
  4    and location# = 83;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

You'd want to see that *zero* along with `location# = 83`, but - there's none:

```
SQL> select location#, count(*)
  2  from test
  3  where cny# = 1
  4    and location# = 83
  5  group by location#;

no rows selected
```

---

One option is to use self-join; just to check what's going on without filter on `location#`:

```
SQL> select a.location#, count(distinct b.rowid) cnt
  2  from test a left join test b on a.location# = b.location# and a.cny# = 1
  3  --where a.location# = 83
  4  group by a.location#;

 LOCATION#        CNT
---------- ----------
        83          0
         1          2
```

With filter:

```
SQL> select a.location#, count(distinct b.rowid) cnt
  2  from test a left join test b on a.location# = b.location# and a.cny# = 1
  3  where a.location# = 83
  4  group by a.location#;

 LOCATION#        CNT
---------- ----------
        83          0
```